# What step am I missing: JSON.parse(result.as_json)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am able to successfully run `result.as_json` to convert a rails object ("result") to a JSON hash. However, I am not able to convert that JSON hash back into a rails object using `JSON.parse`

Here is the error I am seeing:

```
[5] pry> JSON.parse(result.as_json)
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
from /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@x/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `to_json` instead of `as_json` to get string representation for an object in JSON format that could be parsed by `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse({ :x => 1}.to_json)
```

Comment: Agreed.  [`ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) returns a `Hash`, not a JSON string, hence, `to_json` to be used.